# Java BufferedReader acting strange

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I can't understand for the life of me why bufferedreader is not reading the next line in my file. It keeps returning an empty string. I put the reader in a while loop in the proper format. My text file does not contain any special characters. It only contains numbers and some strings delimited by white spaces. I don't get it.

```
//Read from file method
public void readFile(File x) throws IOException{
    File rFile = x;
    String fileLine;
    Transaction holder;
    int Type;
    //This will destroy the current account to add in the new one
    //Main.$acct.destroyTrans();

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(rFile);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        //Gathering initial information about account
        Main.$acct.setName(bufferedReader.readLine());
        Main.$acct.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine()));
        Main.$acct.setTransCount(Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine()));
        Main.$acct.setSC(Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine()));
        //Adding the objects
        while((fileLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //Tokenize the String to extract information
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fileLine," ");          
            //Go through each token and put it into an arrayList
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                list.add(st.nextToken());
            }
            //Grab each piece of data
            Type = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
            //Route the proper objects to their proper places
            switch(Type){
                case 1:
                {
                holder = new Check(Integer.parseInt(list.get(1)), Type,  Double.parseDouble(list.get(3)), Integer.parseInt(list.get(2)));
                Main.$acct.addNewTrans(holder);
                break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                holder = new Deposit(Integer.parseInt(list.get(1)), Type, Double.parseDouble(list.get(5)), Double.parseDouble(list.get(3)),
                Double.parseDouble(list.get(4)));
                Main.$acct.addNewTrans(holder);
                break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                holder = new Transaction(Integer.parseInt(list.get(1)), Type, Double.parseDouble(list.get(4)));
                Main.$acct.addNewTrans(holder);
                break;
                }
                default:
                {}  
            }
            //End of switch
        }
        //End of while loop

        bufferedReader.close();
    }  
    //End of Try
    //Exception handling portion
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" +
            rFile.getName() + "'");               
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '"
            + rFile.getName() + "'");                 
        // Or we could just do this:
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Sample File:**

> billy
>
> 500
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 1 0 1 100
>
> 3 1 Srv. Chrg. 0.15
>
> 2 2 Deposit 100 100 200

Comment: Share a sample of your file.

Comment: Don't rely on the default encoding for `FileReader`, it's a bug waiting to bite you in the bottom.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] !!! This bunch of code (which is terribly formatted) is too much to analyse.

Comment: You'll need to show us *exactly* where your error is, as I ran the sample file and it seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running just fine as long as the input file format and encoding are the standard ones.
Make sure your input file has no redundant line breaks (or an extra line break at the end of the file);
I tested your code with ANSI encoded file, and it worked as expected.

Fix your exception handling to handle general cases - it will help you debug the error.

i.e. do something like this at the end of the method:

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Throw the exception here, or print it to the console...
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Okay, so me and my professor figured it out. Not seen in this code, I had a toString() Method that would write out the information from each account class, and at the end of the toString() I had a "\n" and I also used a bufferedReader.newLine(). So the file had two "\n", hence why it would not read past the first line......Doh!